# AngularJS Slider Range change selection event trigger

Tags: angularjs

I am using Angular slider https://github.com/PopSugar/angular-slider for min and max range selection.
I am not able to call controller function when slider stops .
So how I can get an event trigger like on-change or on-handle-up with the above example.

Used code : `<slider floor="1000" ceiling="100000" ng-model-low=minPackagePrice ng-model-high="maxPackagePrice"></slider>`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looking at the source, there are a lot of undocumented properties you can pass to the directive. [Click here to view the source.](https://github.com/PopSugar/angular-slider/blob/master/slider.js#L101)

```
  scope: {
    floor: '@',
    ceiling: '@',
    values: '=?',
    step: '@',
    highlight: '@',
    precision: '@',
    buffer: '@',
    dragstop: '@',
    ngModel: '=?',
    ngModelLow: '=?',
    ngModelHigh: '=?',
    change: '&'
  },
```

As you can see, there is a `change` property that you can pass an expression in the same manner as `ng-click`.

`<slider change="myFunction()"` should work.

Comment: Hi , its working on changing the slider but its calling every time the change function till I am not releasing the  pointers.How can I add on-handle-up event to this.

Comment: @Arabinda It looks like Line 221 in the source is a function that fires when the dragging stops. On 233, it fires the `change` function. You can try adding the attribute you want `on-handle-up: '&'` and then firing it there instead.  The source code has `scope.$eval(scope.change)`, but I believe that should just be `scope.change()`. I don't see why it would need to be eval'd. So try: `scope.onHandleUp()` on line 233. This repository really needs some polish, but it doesn't look like pull requests are even being looked at.